# GraphX: Given one VertexID get all connected Vertices

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

So basically I have a graph and an ID of a specific vertex in a graph in GraphX.

Given that VertexID, how do I get all directly connected vertexes to that one vertex? (IE, only one edge away).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you want to find all users directly connected to "franklin" (`VertexId` 5L) using example graph from the [GraphX Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#graphx-programming-guide). The simplest and probably the most efficient approach is to use `collectNeighborIds` / `graph.collectNeighbors` followed by `lookup`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeDirection

val direction: EdgeDirection = ???  // In, Out ...
graph.collectNeighborIds(direction).lookup(5L)
```

Another approach is to use `triplets` and `filter` the results:

```scala
// "franklin" is source
graph.triplets.collect {
  case t if t.srcId == 5L => t.dstId
}
```

Of course you can add other direction and pass additional information like `srcAttr`, `dstAttr` or `vertexAttr`. If you prefer  to keep complete triplet you can replace `collect` with `filter`. Nevertheless if you need single edge / vertex lookups Spark is most likely not the best tool for the job.